# Generating a vector consisting of random samples from a PDF distribution

Tags: r

I am somewhat new to R  and I am stuck on a home work question:

Question 1.1:

Let X be a continuous random variable with PDF given by
`fX(x) =(x + 1/2 for 0 < x < 1;`
0 otherwise:

(A) Calculate `P(1/(X + 1) > 2/3)` by working directly from the PDF of X.

(B) Find the PDF of `Y = 1/(X + 1)`.

(C) Using the result you obtained in (B), recalculate the probability obtained in (A).

(D) (Computer Experiment) In R, generate a vector `x = (x1; : : : ; x10;000)` consisting of 10,000 random samples from fX(x). Let `y = (y1; : : : ; y10;000)` where `yi = 1/1+xi`. Draw a histogram of y and compare it with the PDF you found in (B). Calculate the proportion of Y values bigger
than 2/3 and compare it with the exact one you calculated in (A).

I don't fully understand how to do Part D. Code that was tried:

```
x<- runif(10000, min =0, max =1) 
z<- 0.5 + x 
y <- 1/1+z 
hist(y)
```

Code that was suggested by alistaire:

```
x <- seq(0, 1, .0001)
sample(x, 10000, replace = TRUE, prob = x + 0.5)
```

Comment: It's more so extra homework that's really isn't required for the course, but I want to learn how to do it!

Comment: You'll need to post some code examples showing what you've tried before you ask for help. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: x<- runif(10000, min =0, max =1)
> z<- 0.5 + x
> y <- 1/1+z
> hist(y)

This is what I've tried. But, it still doesn't make total sense since the Range of Y is between 1/2 and 1

Comment: There's an unmatched parenthesis in the PDF, but if it's supposed to be x + 1/2, you can do it by setting the probabilities on a sequence: `x <- seq(0, 1, .0001); sample(x, 10000, replace = TRUE, prob = x + 0.5)` It's not very efficient or precise, though; there's probably a better alternative.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble scoping this request. Is this for any-old distribution that you are truncating to the domain of `0 < x < 1` or is this for a standard Normal distribution?

Comment: If this is entirely theoretical and should apply to any distribution, then it's not a coding question. If, on the other hand, it for a particular distribution, there would be methods for integration over limits and there would also be different code for a simulation/sampling approach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two general approaches to solving this problem come to mind.

When the PDF y=fx(x) is known, an efficient approach to simulating is to use the inverse CDF method:

1. Compute the CDF, Y = Fx(x), analytically by integrating
2. Solve for x to get the inverse CDF, x = Fy(Y)
3. Put draws from the uniform (0,1) distribution into the inverse CDF as Y.  The result will be draws from the fx(x) distribution.

Alternatively, you can do draws from some other distribution (like the uniform) and then keep/discard them probabilistically based on the relative heights of the generating and target PDFs.

If this is from a class you are taking, then one of these approaches likely sounds familiar.

Comment: Non-coding questions should be closed as off-topic, rather than answered. Coding questions should be answered with code. This is admittedly an unclear situation with respect to the poster's intent.

Comment: I have no problem with closing a question, but it's bad form to downvote a correct (and accepted) answer because you didn't like the question.

Comment: I'm not so sure it is. Perhaps you should submit your opinion to MetaSO and see what others think about downvoting inappropriate answers.